# Where should I put this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have this snippet that i want to access from a controller or a model but i dont know what file to put it in

```
def cost_to_f(string)
 string.gsub(/[\$,]/, '').to_f
end
```

I tried application controller and application helper and no luck on either

any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68391/how-to-write-a-rails-mixin-that-spans-across-model-controller-and-view).